# Hiding a <td> in a <tr> with CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have to hide a `td` element in a `tr` which has 2 `td`s

Here is the HTML code:

```html
<div class="ms-globalnavicon">
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border:solid 0px red;">
    <tr>
      <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding-right:10px;padding-top:5px;">
        <a href="http://unet.unisys.com" target="_blank">
          <img src="/_layouts/images/SiteIcon.png" alt="Unisys" />
        </a>
      </td>
      <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding-top:9px;">
        <a href="http://google.com">My Site</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

In the above HTML code I need to hide the 2nd `td` element alone in CSS. I put the below CSS but it is hiding both the `td`s.

```css
.ms-globalnavicon table tr td {
  visibility: collapse;
}
```

```html
<div class="ms-globalnavicon">
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border:solid 0px red;">
    <tr>
      <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding-right:10px;padding-top:5px;">
        <a href="http://unet.unisys.com" target="_blank">
          <img src="/_layouts/images/SiteIcon.png" alt="Unisys" />
        </a>
      </td>
      <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding-top:9px;">
        <a href="http://google.com">My Site</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Easiet / safest way is to add a class to target. http://jsfiddle.net/gJvhs/

```css
.hideANDseek {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="ms-globalnavicon">
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border:solid 0px red;">
    <tr>
      <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding-right:10px;padding-top:5px;">
        <a href="http://unet.unisys.com" target="_blank">
          <img src="/_layouts/images/SiteIcon.png" alt="Unisys" />
        </a>
      </td>
      <!-- added the class here -->
      <td class="hideANDseek" align="left" valign="top" style="padding-top:9px;">
        <a href="http://google.com">My Site</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

---

**Edit:** Or you could use jquery to add that class.

http://jsfiddle.net/gJvhs/1/ - works crossbrowser ( also ie6+)

---

**Edit:** Another thing.. http://sizzlejs.com/ - https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/wiki/Sizzle-Home

Comment: Please consider using SO code snippet in place of jsfiddle

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `last-child` selector to only target the last td in the matched set, or for better browser compatibility you should add a class to the td you want to hide and target that specifically.

```
.ms-globalnavicon table tr td:last-child
{
    visibility:collapse;
}
```

**Edit:** Ok, so we need better IE support, and we have to use pure CSS.  Here is a solution that relies on the fact the IE7 and 8 do support `first-child`:

```
.ms-globalnavicon table tr td
{
    display:none;
}
.ms-globalnavicon table tr td:first-child
{
    display:block;
}
```

(note: using `display` rather than `visibility`, and using `block` rather than `table-cell`)

http://jsfiddle.net/BL6nU/2/ (with red border added for clarity)

Comment: +1 - This works, but putting an id on the td element you want and targeting the id would be more robust to change.  I also believe it will work more consistently across different/older browsers.

Comment: @user318197 - if it is the right answer please accept it, and maybe accept some correct answers on your other questions too

Comment: the problem is that I do not have control over the HTML coding. I can only change the rendering by overwriting the CSS. :)

Comment: Then this will probably be your best option, although older versions of IE will not like it.

Comment: @user318197 There is no support for IE8 and lower.

Comment: Hi, it is getting hidden in Google Chrome but not in IE 9... am I missing anything ?

Comment: Is your IE running in compatibility mode for IE7 or 8? Works for me in IE9: http://jsfiddle.net/shanethehat/BL6nU/

Comment: Oh, fine thanks for the answers...need to look for an alternative method.

Comment: @user318197 I hate to advertise, ( no i dont ) but i edited my answer to have jquery solution.

Comment: @user318197 - edited to show a technique that will work on IE8, still working on an IE7 solution which is probably going to have to use some MS propitiatory CSS.

Comment: @user318197 - and there you have it :)

Comment: @shanethehat Well done. Quite the out of the box thinking +1. You're hired! ( Theres no job.. )

Answer (score 3):

The solution above works, but try to use this to show your cells:

```
display: table-cell //show the cells
```

Answer (score 2):

You need `display:none;`

http://jsfiddle.net/9cPYN/

Answer (score 1):

try giving the 1st `<td>` element an `id` and assign the relevant css styling that `id`. This may work.

Answer (score 1):

## Options

You have several options (too many to list them all).  Here are some popular ones based on your attempt:

1. Use the sibling operator
2. Use nth-of-type
3. Directly style (add a class/ID to the row and set `display:none` for that class/id)

---

## Demonstrations

### 1. Sibling operator (`+`)

```css
.ms-globalnavicon table tr td+td {
  visibility: collapse;
}
```

```css
.ms-globalnavicon table tr td+td {
  visibility: collapse;
}
```

```html
<div class="ms-globalnavicon">
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border:solid 0px red;">
    <tr>
      <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding-right:10px;padding-top:5px;">
        <a href="http://unet.unisys.com" target="_blank">
          <img src="/_layouts/images/SiteIcon.png" alt="Unisys" />
        </a>
      </td>
      <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding-top:9px;">
        <a href="http://google.com">My Site</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

## 2. Nth-of-type

```css
.ms-globalnavicon table tr td:nth-of-type(2n){
   display: none;
}
```

```css
.ms-globalnavicon table tr td:nth-of-type(2n) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="ms-globalnavicon">
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border:solid 0px red;">
    <tr>
      <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding-right:10px;padding-top:5px;">
        <a href="http://unet.unisys.com" target="_blank">
          <img src="/_layouts/images/SiteIcon.png" alt="Unisys" />
        </a>
      </td>
      <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding-top:9px;">
        <a href="http://google.com">Link 1</a>
      </td>
      <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding-top:9px;">
        <a href="http://google.com">Link 2</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

FROM, the website MAmirHamza.com
Use both lines together, like this way

```
.table-right-1 { 
    visibility: hidden;
    display: none;
}
```